# What are the advantages and disadvantages of a double bubble fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design

Double bubble is mostly used for Cargo Aircraft with 2 intersecting circles which is in other words: they are 2 floor which are used for more space for freight and also passengers. this type of fuselage mostly used in the past by some small airlines but today they are only used for cargo. i wonder to know all the things above mentioned by me are right or not?
and the other question is that what ARE advantages and disadvantages of A380 fuselage? and how it is designed that able to carry a large number of passengers although its fuselage is not double bubble?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation. SE! I cleaned up your question a little bit. Use the edit button if you want to make additional changes or additions.

Comment: I feel your "other question" should be asked separately, but we'll see what others think.

Comment: I agree with @Federico, the two questions are distinct and should be asked separately.

Comment: I agree as well.

Comment: if you think these are 2 separate questions, you should close as too broad, @GdD

Comment: @EfeBallı same for you

Answer (score 1):

Double bubble is the lightest way to make a pressurized fuselage taller than it is wide.  It maintains the pressure hull elements, skins and formers, closest to pure tension, like a balloon, so they can be a bit lighter since they see little bending stress from pressure (only the interconnecting floor beams see significant bending loads, from the weight of the payload).

The A380 went with an ovalized cross section because it provides a better packaging compromise when you want two decks of roughly the same floor area, although it would be somewhat heavier than a DB cross section because the frame elements of the partially flattened sides are subject to a certain amount of bending because the pressure loads are trying to circular-ize the oval (the floor beams help but the oval sections away from the beams are still subject to that stress).

Think about what would happen if you really cranked up the pressure inside the A380, and imagine how the pressure hull would deform under stress; it would swell out to a more circular shape except where retained by the floor beams, before going "POP" (you'd end up with a kind of "triple bubble" before it went bang).  That deformation load trying to make the oval a circle has to be absorbed as bending loads in the frames, so they have to be heavier than they would be if they were already purely circular.

The packaging advantages over a pure double bubble make it worth the weight penalty.

The original double bubble pressure hull was the [Curtiss C-46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_C-46_Commando), which was originally designed as a pressurized airliner (otherwise they would have used an oval cross section), and used the configuration to make a pressure hull that was a light as possible while keeping it relatively narrow.  Then you had the [Boeing 377 Stratocruiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_377_Stratocruiser), which also went that way in order to graft a passenger cabin on top of a B-29 fuselage and wing without making it too heavy.

[image]

Comment: "only the interconnecting floor beams see significant bending loads, from the weight of the payload" - however, the bending is limited by the crosswise tension in the floor, which resists the outward pressure on the walls. The floor's loadbearing capability actually increases with altitude, which can be useful if you hit an air pocket.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add two other reasons for the A380's double bubble design.

The A380's fuselage needs to bear much larger vertical bending loads compared to horizontal, the wing lift (which is sometimes greater than the aircraft weight) and the main landing gear impact are two forces that bend the fuselage upwards from the center. The nose landing gear impact and horizontal stabilizer forces are two smaller forces that create vertical bending. Whereas the horizontal (side to side) bending forces are limited to gust loads on the fuselage (pretty minor), forces from the vertical stabilizer (which is actually bending+torsional) and nose landing gear forces from steering on the takeoff/landing roll and taxiing. So it pays to have a larger MOI for vertical bending. If we compare a  circular, vertical (top and bottom) double bubble and side to side double bubble of the same cross section, the vertical double bubble will have the highest MOI for vertical bending.

Another concern is operational, it is easier to connect multiple jetways to one side of the aircraft on the upper and lower decks for faster loading. Higher class passengers also like being separated from the plebs by using their separate jetways to reach their part of the aircraft, which is often the upper deck for the A380. Twin aisles on both decks will also help with passengers reaching their seats easier. Other fuselage cross sections would require multiple aisles (of which only the outer ones would help with evacuation) or large amounts of scooting and "sorry, may I?" moments in a seat row.

Speaking of evacuation, having lots of exits and placing people as evenly as possible between exits is easiest with a vertical double bubble design. With other cross sections, people closer to the center will take longer to reach an exit.